# Write InputStream to a file

Tags: java, file, inputstream

I have an object, in this object I have an InputStream which contains a file.

I want to write what is inside of InputStream to a file inside of a folder.

How would I go about doing this in Core Java?

I was able to print out each line of the InputStream using BufferedReader and .readLine(), however I want the entire file wrote to disk not just what is inside of it.

Hopefully this makes sense, thank you.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Java 7 or above you can use [`java.nio.file.Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html):

```java
InputStream in = obj.getInputStrem();
Path file = ...;
Files.copy(in, path);
```

It also supports different options *(see [`CopyOption`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/CopyOption.html) implementations like [`StandardCopyOption`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardCopyOption.html) and [`LinkOption`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/LinkOption.html))*

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure its out there already, you could google it. But as you asked about writing to a file inside of a folder, assuming the InputStream variable is named "`input`":

```
FileOutputStream output = null;
try {
    // Create folder (if it doesn't already exist)
    File folder = new File("<path_to_folder>\\<folder_name>");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdirs();
    }
    // Create output file
    output = new FileOutputStream(new File(folder, "<file_name>"));
    // Write data from input stream to output file.
    int bytesRead = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} catch (IOException ioex) {
    ioex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (output != null) {
            output.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        ioex.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Also close InputStream if no longer needed.
    try {
        if (input != null) {
            input.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        ioex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will that write everything include file icon etc... or just the contents of the file? I did google but I was getting confused by it all, I have not asked a question on here for months.

Comment: It will write everything including icon, however: the `<file_name>` must include extension for the icon to appear eg for a text file, "`mytextfile.txt`" or for a mp3 audio file, "`song.mp3`" etc.

Comment: Also, 
`<path_to_folder>` eg `C:\\Users\\<Username>\\Desktop` and
`<folder_name>` eg `MyFolder`